# How type is deduced from `auto` variable

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Based on my understanding, the type of a variable declared with auto is deduced from its initializer.

```
int main()
{
  unordered_map<string, int> dict;
  dict.insert({"a", 10});
  cout << dict["a"] << endl;

  auto iter = dict.find("a");
  if (iter != dict.end())
    iter->second = 30;

  cout << dict["a"] << endl;

  unordered_map<string, int>::iterator iterModify = dict.find("a");
  iterModify->second = 300;

  unordered_map<string, int>::const_iterator iterNonModify = dict.find("a");
  iterNonModify->second = 400; //  error: read-only variable is not assignable
}
```

In above example, as you can see, it seems that the type of auto is further constrained based on the usage of the defined variable `iter` and it's type is `unordered_map<string, int>::iterator`. However, without the following lines, how the compiler deduces the type of the auto correctly?

Question> Is it true that the "the type of a variable declared with auto is deduced from its initializer only"? If that is the case, why the deduced type of iter is of `unordered_map<string, int>::iterator`?

Comment: What do you think the type would be without the following lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is different from `const`.  You can define:

```
const auto i = 5;
auto j = 5;
i = 6; //error const violation
j = 6; //OK
```

Similarly, you can define `auto&`, `const auto&`, `auto&&`, `volatile auto`, etc.

Because `find` has two function prototypes, it chooses which one based on the `const`ness of the variable, which you have defined at mutable, so it chooses the mutable version.

In C++ standard language, there is a difference in the `cv-qualifier` (const, volatile) and the `type-specifier` (`auto`, `auto&`, `auto&&`), see section 7.1.6 for more details.  http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Answer (score 3):

> Question> Is it true that the "the type of a variable declared with
>   auto is deduced from its initializer only"?

Yes. The compiler does not take in consideration what you'll do next with that variable.

Thus, if you try to write a code like this:

```
auto x;
x = 5;
```

It won't compile, because `x` has no initializer when you declare it.

[Stroustrup himself](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#auto) describes this feature as "*auto -- deduction of a type from an initializer*"

### Edit:

> If that is the case, why the deduced type of iter is of
>   unordered_map::iterator?

Because that is the return type of [unordered_map.find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) as in `auto iter = dict.find("a");`

Comment: This doesn't address my question. Please see my updated question.

Comment: you may want to check this first http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find

Comment: That is exactly the same link I provided in my answer, as supporting the facts I stated...

Comment: @q0987 What exactly is your problem with this answer? It seems to give all the information you asked for. (It would be even better if it had a reference to the Standard, though..)